# Disable html in Codeigniter 3 Error Handling

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, output, codeigniter-3

I'm developing API and when an PHP error appears a bunch of html tags and css appear making somewhat intelligible the response.

Is it possible to activate plain text for error some way? I know Codeigniter supports this, as HTML/CSS aren't printed when executen CI via php-cli.

Comment: check your application/error folder, there are the error files located, also see [Error Handling](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/errors.html?highlight=error)

Comment: @Vickel The API is only secondary use, I do want html for the web access, I only want to disable for API